# How to solve the equation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}/\binom{n+x}{n} =\frac{3}{2}$ for $x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I find this problem on [this page](https://www.facebook.com/GTRmath/photos/a.1410681185813536.1073741832.1407507379464250/1536183123263341/?type=1&theater).

Find $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2\displaystyle\binom{n+x}{n}}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: I cannot access the image.

Comment: The link/image contains no additional information. The problem is really just solving that equation.

Answer (score 9):

Writing the binomial coefficient as a [beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html) and then expressing this beta function in terms of its integral representation (Euler), we can find out what function the series evaluates to for general $x$, with $x>-1$:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2\binom{n+x}{n}}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(n,x+1\right)}}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n-1}\left(1-t\right)^{x}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{n-1}}{n}\right]\left(1-t\right)^{x}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left[-\frac{\ln{\left(1-t\right)}}{t}\right]\left(1-t\right)^{x}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(1-t\right)^{x}\ln{\left(1-t\right)}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z^{x}\ln{\left(z\right)}}{1-z}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-z^{x}}{1-z}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\gamma+\psi{\left(x+1\right)}\right]\\
&=\psi^{(1)}{\left(x+1\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where $\psi{\left(x\right)}$ and $\psi^{(1)}{\left(x\right)}$ are, respectively, the [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html) and the [trigamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigammaFunction.html). In other words, we must solve the equation $\psi^{(1)}{\left(x+1\right)}=\frac32$. Numerically, the solution $x$ has an approximate value,

$$x\approx 0.0656560393745264854445863686\dots,$$

but I'm very pessimistic about our chances of finding a closed form for this value. In particular $x$ is not a rational number.

---

**Edit:**

After encountering the closed form of a possibly related series proposed by Chris'sis in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010916/computing-sum-n-1-infty-frac-psi-left-fracn12-right-binom2n), I'm about ready to admit that anything is possible. At the very least, I'm much less confident that the possible existence of a closed form can be altogether ruled out.